# Radio Buttons Check + SQL Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml, radio-button

I have a few questions on my form with either an acceptable or an unacceptable option which is linked to a radio button. The issue i am having is that my check event is firing once when i check and firing again when i uncheck it, i am unsure of how to modify my code so that it only fires once per each questions answer, would this be the correct way to achieve what i am doing and insert the answers into SQL as it is semi working apart from the events which fire twice:

```
string answer1 = "Acceptable";
string answer2 = "Not Acceptable";

string n1;
string n2;
string n3;
string n4;

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3}", SQLSERVER_ID, SQLDatabaseName, SQLServerLoginName, SQLServerPassword));
    string query = "INSERT INTO Answers(Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4) VALUES (@Option1, @Option2, @Option3, @Option4";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    conDatabase.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Option1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = n1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Option2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = n2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Option3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = n3;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Option4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = n4;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conDatabase.Close();
}
```

My xaml code is:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radio1a" GroupName="Question1" Checked="radioButton1_Checked"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="radio1b" GroupName="Question1" Unchecked="radioButton2_Checked"/>

<RadioButton x:Name="radio2a" GroupName="Question2" Checked="radioButton1_Checked"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="radio2b" GroupName="Question2" Unchecked="radioButton2_Checked"/>
```

Lastly my check is if the radio button1 for acceptable is clicked then 'n1' will be set to answer1 (acceptable) and if the radio button2 for unacceptable is clicked then 'n1' will be set to answer2 (unacceptable) - n1 being number 1 (the first question on my form):

```
private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Check();
}

private void radioButton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Check();
}

public void Check()
{
    if (radio1a.IsChecked == true)
    {
        n1 = answer1;
    }
    else if (radio1b.IsChecked == true)
    {
        n1 = answer2;
    }

    if (radio2a.IsChecked == true)
    {
        n2 = answer1;
    }
    else if (radio2b.IsChecked == true)
    {
        n2 = answer2;
    }
    .... etc.
}
```

Comment: Cant really get what you are trying. So there are some questions with multiple radio-buttons per question? When an answer is checked, it should fire? Do it has to fire again when an answer is switched? Should it even be possible to switch the answer? Or are you going to submit all answers once by a button or something else?

Comment: @C4ud3x Each question has 2 options either acceptable or unacceptable. Question 1 will be inserted into the first column in the db and question 2 will be inserted into the second column etc. The user will make all of their selections and then click submit which will insert into the db. I noticed it is firing twice because i had a message box attached to 1a/2a radio buttons and they were appearing twice every time i changed to a different selection. When i change my selection the event is firing again, when i check and uncheck which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: If u check one answer the event is fired twice? And by the way: remove the "== true" from your if's. "IsChecked" already returns a boolean, so if(radio.IsChecked) will be enough. For false just go for if(!radio.IsChecked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.

Imagine you check your first radiobutton. After that you are checking the second one. Your function *check()* will still be true for the first radiobutton, because it is still checked!

Go this way: If radioButton1 or 2 is checked get the name of the button. Pass this button-name to your check()-function and switch it. This way it will only fire for the radiobutton which got checked, not for all that are checked too.

```
private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var radioFired = (RadioButton)sender;
        Check(radioFired.Name);
    }

private void radioButton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var radioFired = (RadioButton)sender;
        Check(radioFired.Name);
    }

public void Check(string radioName)
    {
        switch(radioName)
        {
            case "radio1a":
               n1 = answer1;
               break;
            case "radio1b":
                n1 = answer2;
                break;
            etc...
         }
    }
```

As a hint for cleaner coding:
There is no need to compare a returned boolean to "true" or "false".

Instead of this..

```
if(radioButton.IsChecked == true)
```

better go this way for comparing true..

```
if(radioButton.IsChecked)
```

or like this for comparing to false..

```
if(!radioButton.IsChecked)
```

If it is checked, 'radioButton.IsChecked' is true. If the value is true, your code will get executed. Its just like writing if(true) which will get executed aswell.

---

**If you would rather like to stay with your code:**

*Deleted this part. Wasnt working. Better take my solution above.*

Comment: Great answer, i did think about using one originally but wasn't sure about how to use it in this manner. Anyway the switch case was exactly what i needed, now the event is firing correctly, thanks!